# Following as it did

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunctions, time, as

I came across this sentence -

> *Although his (Nirmal) detainment (in prison) lasted only a day or two, the experience had a profoundly unsettling effect on Nirmal, **following as it did** on his rejection by Nilimas's (Nirmal's wife) family and his separation from his own.*

I can't understand the meaning of "following as it did". I want to know about the usage and analysis of this wording. 
I understood the meaning that Nirmal's stay in prison had a great impact on his life, following his separation from both the family.

Answer (score 2):

The expression *as SUBJ AUX* (*AUX* being a finite form of any auxiliary verb) has two broad uses:

1. To inform the reader that a ‘hypothetical’ event in fact has the degree of reality expressed by *AUX*:

   > If the committee finds your application inadequate, *as it may*, it will ask for more information. — *This is approximately equivalent to* The committee may find your application inadequate; if they do, they will ask for more information.
   >
   > When the seal is broken, *as yours was*, the red post pops up.  *This is approximately equivalent to* Your seal was broken; in this circumstance, the red post pops up.
2. To disambiguate a potentially ambiguous expression. That’s what is in play in your example. Lacking the phrase *as it did*, the phrase *following his rejection ...* would probably be parsed as modifying the entire preceding clause and would be understood to imply that it was the *unsettling effect* which followed the rejection. The phrase *as it did* sets the subjects of the two clauses, *experience* and *it*, in parallel; we understand from this that it was because the experience followed the rejection that the experience had an unsettling effect.

Comment: As for your second point, if in my original sentence "as it did" was omitted and only "...following his rejection ...." was there then also it would mean the same thing. Now what meaning "as it did" adds on to this sentence?

Comment: @Man_From_India Without "as it did" the *following* phrase is merely a temporal reference point. With "as it did" the phrase is identified as contributing to the unsettling effect: detainment was unsettling *because* it followed rejection and separation.

Comment: I am afraid I didn't understand it properly. I believe this sentence means this - "he was detained in custody. It is for very little time, one or two days at max. But it's effect was huge. Following his detainment he was rejected from family."

Answer (score 0):

"following as it did" means that the effect of the detainment was *enhanced* by the prior bad experiences. To use another example from today, "Breaking a nail is normally an nuisance, but following as it did upon the cats throwing up, discovering an ice dam leak in the garage and bedroom, and needing to get bloodwork done during a snowstorm, it nearly made me cry."

E.g., here are all the things that happened before I broke my nail. The cumulative effect of all those made the nail-breakage more traumatic than normal.

Comment: Do you want to say "enhanced" or "made more unsettling"?

Comment: To enhance something is to make it more whatever-it-is. Creepy music enhances the scary mood of a horror movie. Nice perfume enhances the beauty of the flower. See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enhance?s=t . I'm using "enhance" exactly as I intended. :)

Comment: _Enhanced_'s meaning of "intensify" has plenty of established usage, but I'm thinking it's confusing to a reader, especially an EFL learner, because the primary meaning of _enhance_ is to "make better", or at least it carries "improvement" as a strong connotation. For example, what does it mean to enhance a bad kitchen? Or to enhance a detainment? Or its effect? Anyway, replacing "enhanced" with something else is just a suggestion to make the answer clearer.

Comment: By this time, hopefully the comments have elaborated on the possible meanings. ;)